# Multi-step Javascript timing algorithm

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, timeout, timing

I need to write a function with the following requirements:

- Runs `f(A)` every `m` seconds
- `f(A)` makes a HTTP request `f(B)` every `n` seconds
- If the request `f(B)` fails `o` consecutive times within a single `f(A)` test, the next `f(A)` is run every `p` seconds
- If the `f(B)` does not fail `o` consecutive times within one `f(A)` test, the next `f(A)` is run every `m` seconds, as usual.

I was able to do this:

```
function runTests(ms) {
  let runTestsMS = ms || m;

  setTimeout(() => {
    let count = 0;
    setInterval(async () => {
      try {
        await axios.get('...');
        count = 0;
        runTestsMS = ms || m;
      } catch (error) {
        count += 1;
        if (count === o) {
          runTests(p);
        }
      }
    }, n);

    runTests(runTestsMS);
  }, runTestsMS);
}

runTests();
```

This function does not perform rule 3 above. If consecutive failures are made, the next `f(A)` is still run every `m` seconds.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` returns immeadiately without awaiting anything. You have to `await` a timer inside a loop:

```
 const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms);

 async function runTests(ms) {
  while(true) {
   let count = 0;
   while(count < 3) {
     try {
      await axios.get('...');      
      break;    
     } catch (error) {
      count += 1;
      await timer(n);
     }
   }
   await timer(m);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code , the function `runTests()` is invoked without a parameter which is okay since inside the function you have specified   `let runTestsMS = ms || m` .

The problem comes when neither `ms` nor `m` have actual values .

Comment: The values (m, n, o, p) are constants declared elsewhere.

Comment: Please post the code that is carries the m,n,o,p .So that I can understand the logic in your code better .